# Show a series is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let
$$
f(z) = \sum_n z^{n!}
$$

I am trying to show that $f(z)$ is analytic on the open unit disk ${|z| <1}$.

My thought is to find its radius of convergence $R$, but this series does not have a form of a power series (which I learned how to find $R$ from the various tests) so I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can express you serie as : $\sum_n b_n z^n$ with $b_n = n$ if $n = k!$ for some $k$ and $b_n = 0$ for the other cases. Then, according to the Hadamard theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) the radius of convergence $R$ satistfies $\frac1R = \limsup |b_n|^{\frac1n} = 1 $, thus $R = 1$.